# jQuery sortable, how to limit sorting rows only by clicking on specified element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using sortable in following way

```
$("#fieldsTable").sortable({
    items: 'tr'
});
```

But now the table row can be dragged by clicking on anywhere inside the row.

I want to have an image inside the table row and limit users to drag from there to reorder the row. Please let me know how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `handle` option:

```
$("#fieldsTable").sortable({
    items: 'tr',
    handle: '.dragImage'
});
```

Assuming that you set a CSS class of `dragImage` on the image within the row.

More info in the [API docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-handle).

Comment: well slightly quicker...+1 for you.